# Why am I getting this results in my ArrayList instead of the integer values?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello and Thanks for all your peoples help.

I am making a concentration game as a learning project. I was having some problems with the random generator working right which was solved by Jeeter in this thread. [Jeeter's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827533/how-to-create-a-number-generator-that-will-only-pick-a-number-1-time)

and this is the code which I am using to get the numbers and store them into an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<int[]> al = new ArrayList<int[]>();

int offsetX = 130;
int offsetY = 100;

switch(Game.difficulity){
case EASY:
    GameConstants.cardsToDraw = 6;
    //generate cards
    UniqueRandoms randpEA = new UniqueRandoms(GameConstants.cardsToDraw);
    int[] cardsEA = new int[GameConstants.cardsToDraw];
    System.out.print("The Picks are: "); //Testing purposes only.

    for (int i = 0; i < GameConstants.cardsToDraw; i++) {
       cardsEA[i] = randpEA.nextInt();  // grabs the results so they can be manulipated
       al.add(cardsEA);                 // add the results to an ArrayList
       System.out.print(cardsEA[i] + ", "); //testing to see what is chosen

       // this line just shows the result as cards onscreen.        
       handler.addcard(new GameCard((offsetX) + i*90, (GameConstants.CENTER_Y - offsetY), cardsEA[i], res));
                        }
      //end of generate cards
      System.out.print("\n");
      System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
      Game.state = GameState.EASY_GAME;
      break;
```

This is the easy code block to keep this post short.

the results are this when I run the program:
Cards to draw: 6
The Picks are: 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6,
 
Contents of al: [[I@44d74990, [I@44d74990, [I@44d74990, [I@44d74990, [I@44d74990, [I@44d74990]

What my question is why am I getting the crazy numbers instead of the actual integers and how can I fix this?

Because I have to do the following:

1. Store the results
2. Duplicate the results
3. Shuffle the ArrayList
4. retrieve the values when I need to use them

So far I am trying to store the results and it does not look like it doing what I expect and then I have to figure out how to duplicate the results in the ArrayList.

My GitHub Project:[Here](https://github.com/rtester47/Concentration)

Comment: what is the type of `al` ?

Comment: I'm just going to say that Jeeter's solution is quite bad...

Comment: @ZongZhengLi what does that have to do with getting my values in the array to store right? nothing, so why post useless comments like this if you think it is bad and can do better then show an example and explain why so other can learn from it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend you or Jeeter. It's just that the implementation and algorithm are both...bad, especially for beginners to learn from. You've posted it, so it's relevant for me to comment on it, though I admit it is not the most constructive comment. I may just provide a better example later.

Comment: @smcg the al is this i forgot to add it before i posted this question and I went back in and added it but you already commented. ArrayList<int[]> al = new ArrayList<int[]>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facts:
1) ArrayList cannot store primitives, hence your integers are stored as Integer wrappers

2) the crazy numbers are memory references of the respective Integer objects, and for some reason the toString() implementation of that object return the memory locations

hence you have to loop the ArrayList and use get() to get the values

edit:

just noticed

```
cardsEA[i] = randpEA.nextInt();  // grabs the results so they can be manulipated
  al.add(cardsEA);
```

you need to change it as

```
cardsEA[i] = randpEA.nextInt();  // grabs the results so they can be manulipated
  al.add(cardsEA[i]);
```

to get the desired result

Comment: I tried that but i get some other errors that i do not know how to fix. it wants me to change other stuff in my code and when i tell it to do it I still have errors that I don't know how to fix. I will change it and get the erros and post them here.

Comment: can you post the error?
i think the problem arise where you defined the ArrayList
you defined it to have an array on int[]
so first change it,`ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
then use the above code, but for safety
`al.add(new Integer(cardsEA[i]));`
this isnt really necessary since autoboxing take care of it

Comment: Thanks I thought the way i was initiating my ArrayList looked wrong but eclipse did that. it works just the way i was suspecting the results to be. would it be ok to ask how i can duplicate the values in the list once they are in the list or should I ask it in another question?

Comment: depends on what kinda duplicate you need
if you need a hard copy ie: all values are copied from one to another you have to loop the array list and push to the other
if you just need to refer the same set of Integer objects, you can ust use a simple assignment, `ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(oldList);`

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Lists cannot store primitives but they certainly can store primitive arrays because arrays are objects. It is not printing the memory address of Integers (there are no Integers nor Integers[] in his list), it is printing the memory address of the arrays.

Comment: what you are saying is true but i dont see how it contradict my statements :S

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually loop through the ArrayList and then through each array in the list to print each value.  What you need to do is:

```
 System.out.print("Contents of al: ");
 for(int[] ia: al){ 
    for(int i: ia)
       System.out.print(i + ", ");
 }
 System.out.println();
```

What it doing now is printing the reference of each array in the list.

Comment: I do not have to print out the contents of the array the printing of it out is for my own debugging what I need to do is make sure I have integers in my arraylist instead of that crazy crap it is showing. and then i need to duplicate the numbers stored in the arraylist.

Comment: This will do that.  It gives you what you want.  The "crazy crap" is the memory address of each in[] in the list.  If you want to see the contents, you'll have to access each element of each array.

Comment: By declaring an `ArrayList<int[]>` you can actually be very sure it only contains `int[]`s. Even if you try to put something else in it, ignore the warnings and compile anyway you will get an uncompilable source code exception at runtime and the program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

try printing `al.toString()` instead of `al`

`al.toString()` will format its contents to a readable form.

EDIT: but if `al` contains `int[]` follow the answer posted by Thomas

Answer (score 0):

By this little snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameConstants.cardsToDraw; i++) {
   cardsEA[i] = randpEA.nextInt();
   al.add(cardsEA);
```

It seems like what you are wanting to do is not have an `ArrayList<int[]>` because what you have now is an ArrayList of arrays. By doing `al.add(cardsEA);` on each iteration you are just adding the same array to the list repeatedly. When you try to print the list you are getting the memory address of the array for each time you added it in the loop. It seems like this what you are wanting:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
```

Then change the line in the loop to this:

```
al.add(cardsEA[i]);
```

Though if this is the case you don't need to create the array at all. You can change your loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0, card; i < GameConstants.cardsToDraw; i++) {
   card = randpEA.nextInt();
   al.add(card);
   System.out.print(card + ", ");

   handler.addcard(new GameCard((offsetX) + i*90, (GameConstants.CENTER_Y - offsetY), card, res));
```

Alternatively if you want both the array and the list something you can do is this:

```
Integer[] cardsEA = new Integer[GameConstants.cardsToDraw];
```

Then don't bother working with the list until after the loop and do either this:

```
// declaration
List<Integer> al;

// after the loop
al = Arrays.asList(cardsEA);
```

Or if you need ArrayList reference instead of List do this:

```
// declaration
ArrayList<Integer> al;

// after the loop
al = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(cardsEA));
```

Or:

```
// declaration
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// after the loop
al.addAll(Arrays.asList(cardsEA));
```

Lots of ways to make a list from an array. If you want to create the list as starting as empty, if possible instantiate it as `new ArrayList<Integer>(GameConstants.cardsToDraw)` because then the ArrayList will potentially not need to be internally resized.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this for me, you said the same as a person above did. cardsToDraw is the amount of cards for each difficulty easy 6, normal 12, hard 18, and extreme all 24. after that I need to duplicate the results because this is a card matching game and I need pairs of numbers to check to see if the cards are the same. that is why i needed an ArrayList is I some how have to add the duplicates to the list. still trying to figure that part out.  Also I tried to just make it cards but for some reason the cardsToDraw was not updating right and I had to make 4 seperate ones.